# How to use Thinkpad trackpoint to vertical scroll on a MacBook?

Tags: macos, touchpad, thinkpad, scrolling, trackpoint

I just bought a Thinkpad tablet 2 bluetooth keyboard to use with a MacBook. The thing I found difficult was that I'm not able to scroll like trackpad anymore. I have to click the scroll bar on the right. I read that press and hold middle button and use trackpoint to scroll, but it does not work.

I tried usboverdrive, choose Middle button - Move to scroll, it does not work.

How can I use trackpoint to scroll on a MacBook?

Comment: It's usually a 2-finger drag to scroll on a trackpad, with nothing 3rd party interfering.

Comment: yes I'm talking about using a bluetooth keyboard, which has a trackpoint as a mouse. The keyboard does not have a trackpad.

Comment: a trackpoint? Is that one of those rubbery dots in the middle of the letters? I've never used one. i thought you meant a trackpad. if the keyboard has no scroll-wheel equivalent, maybe there's some further hint in the manual.

Comment: Yeah you are right, the rubber dots usually in a Thinkpad laptop. I have a bluetooth keyboard identical to that. internet says hold middle button and use trackpoint equals to 2 finger scroll, but it does not work on mine.

Comment: The Mac probably has no clue what it's looking at

Comment: No idea how PC is able to identify middle button + trackpoint as scroll natively, but trackpoint is great when you don't want to move your hand away from keyboard when typing

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem is 80% solved with an app called Smart scroll, where you can use Grab scroll. A bit different but much better than dragging the bar.